# server side email validation with node and Express

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, validation

I am working on a web app, and I wanted to do email validation on my server side using javascript, but I am a bit confused as to how to structure my document, and how to make it all work.

I am using node/Express, and I am using Jade for my templates. I want my user login page to be about to validate an email as soon as the user clicks out of the box (using AJAX calls). I have a folder called lib, where I have a validation.js file where I intend to have all my validation code.

I also have a navigation.js file where I am using all of my AJAX calls.

validation.js

```
function checkEmail(userEmail) {

    var email = userEmail
    var emailFilter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;

    if (!emailFilter.test(email.value)) {
    //alert('Please provide a valid email address');
    email.focus;
    return false;
 }
 function checkPassword(userPassword){
    var password = userPassword; 
    var passwordFilter = /^[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*]{6,16}$/

    if (!passwordFilter.test(password.value)){
        password.focus; 
        return false;
    }
 }
```

navigation.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    console.log("DOCUMENT IS READY!");

    var viewsWrapper = $("#views-wrapper");
    var loginButton = $("#login-button");
    var registerButton = $("#register-button");

    // Login Link
    // TODO: Unclear if needed
    $("ul li.login").click(function() {
        $.get('/login', function(data) {
            viewsWrapper.html(data);
        });
    });


    // Login Button
    loginButton.click(function(e) {


        // TODO: Input validation needed


        var loginData = { username: $("#username").val(), password: $("#password").val() };

        $( "#username" ).blur(function() {
            if (!checkEmail(username)){
                alert( "Handler for .blur() called." );
            } 
        });
        $( "#username" ).blur(function() {
            if (!checkPassword(password)){
                alert( "Handler for .blur() called." );
            } 
        });

        e.preventDefault();
        $.post('/login', loginData, function(data) {
            $('body').html(data);
        });
    });

..... (Still code after this but not relevant)
```

I edited my code so that I used some o the comments from below. It is still not working because I am not getting the alert message. Does it have to do when I call:

```
        if (!checkPassword(username)){
            alert( "Handler for .blur() called." );
        }
```

Am I actually passing in the username when I do this, or should I be using the loginData somehow?

Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If this is an HTML 5 page you can take advantage the built in email validation. http://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/html5-form-validation/ Unfotunatly this would be different than the regex you specified but writing an email regex is harder than it initially appears.

I would also suggest that since you already have the validations written in javascript you could apply the same validations in javascript on the webpage itself. This would save you a potentially delay inducing ajax call.

In terms of how to apply the validation when they click out, you can use the blur event which jQuery provides a convenient method to use. http://api.jquery.com/blur/

Answer (score 0):

You can check the email after the user clicks out of the email input box using the jQuery focusout or blur events:

```
$('#txtEmail').focusout(function(){
    checkEmail();
});
```

Comment: I made some changes to my question, and to the methods above. When I run the code, I do not get the alert, should i be referenceing loginData? I also changed validation.js so that the methods take in the username and password parameters.

Comment: I would pass $("#password").val() to checkPassword. The value of password is likely undefined. Also, having $("#username").blur inside the click event handler doesn't make sense. These are separate events: blur; onclick. Looks like you've got 2 .blur event handlers which you could combine